# Facebook API Returns Empty Table When Trying to View Likes on a Page Post

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to gather all people who liked a certain post on a Facebook page. 
This is what I use 
`https://graph.facebook.com/1421518438141373_1561986067427942/likes?limit=200000&access_token=My_Access_Token`
However it returns an empty JSON table.

Also the number of the likes on the post is pretty huge, around 200K. Any idea how to avoid pagination and got all of the info at once?

Comment: double check you are using a Page Access Token to retrieve a valid response

Comment: You can not “avoid pagination”. The `limit` parameter allows you to specify how many results you want in one response, but it itself is _limited_ for most endpoints. For anything that goes beyond the maximum limit possible, you _will_ have to paginate through the results.